Congestion in ERC20, not allowing me access to my transfer unless I pay 10% or it will be lost
I transferred 3mil from Coinbase Wallet, CounbaseETF.  I was informed that the transfer was congested in the ERC20 network and I will not have access unless I pay a 10% fee within 20 days.  Is this legit?

No, it is not. If the network is congested the worst is higher the gasprice, so the cost of the transaction. Even if it's not picked, it would be dropped after maxi 24h, so that is obviously a way to get money from you.

No, this scenario sounds like a common cryptocurrency scam. Legitimate exchanges and services typically do not impose additional fees for transferring funds or accessing your own assets. Additionally, requests for urgent payments or time-limited offers are often red flags for scams.
It's essential to verify the authenticity of any communication or notification you receive regarding your cryptocurrency transactions. Always double-check the sender's email address or domain, and consider reaching out to the exchange or service provider directly through their official channels to confirm the legitimacy of any claims or requests for fees.
In this case, I would advise you to contact Coinbase support directly through their official website or app to inquire about the supposed transfer congestion and the request for a 10% fee. Do not proceed with any payments until you have verified the situation with Coinbase support.
